# Why isn't the circuit breaking of ISTIO working?

Tags: kubernetes, istio, circuit-breaker

- with istio 1.4.6

I configured Kubernetes using resources such as `service`, `deployment`.
I also configured `gateway`, `virtual service`, and `destination rules` to implement circuit breakers.

The composition diagram is as follows. (**number of Pod's replica is two. & I operate only one version of app.**)

[image]

I wrote `VirtualServices` and `DestinationRules` to use circuit breakers

#### VirtualService

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: reviews-virtual-service
spec:
  gateways:
  - reviews-istio-gateway
  hosts:
  - reviews
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: reviews-service
        port:
          number: 80
```

#### DestinationRules

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: reviews-destination-rule
spec:
  host: reviews
  trafficPolicy:
    loadBalancer:
      simple: ROUND_ROBIN
    outlierDetection:
      baseEjectionTime: 1m
      consecutiveErrors: 1
      interval: 1s
      maxEjectionPercent: 100
```

Here, I expect that if more than one error occurs in `reviews-app`, all pods will be excluded from the load balancing list for a minute.
Therefore, I expected the circuit breaking to work as below.

[image]

However, contrary to expectations, **circuit breakers did not work**, and **error logs were continuously being recorded** in reviews-app.

**Why isn't the circuit breaker working?**

Comment: Why did you use very old and unsupported istio version: https://istio.io/latest/docs/releases/supported-releases/#support-status-of-istio-releases?

Comment: It is difficult to do version up due to internal reasons.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the problem is not about Circuit Breaking, but about the usage of Virtual Services and Destination Rules.

For example, if using a Virtual Service with a Gateway, its host should probably be of public host, like http://amce.io

The host of the Destination Rule should probably be that of the Kubernetes Service.

Comment: But, if this is host's problem, Isn't the `reviews-app` communication not working at all? (And I wrote the above host under a virtual host name.)

Comment: well how do you access that service?

Comment: I called `reviews-app` API using the gateway external IP. And I checked the responses of `reviews-app`.

Comment: did you try to specify `reviews-service` as the host in the DestinationRule. According to the docs: The name of a service from the service registry. Service names are looked up from the platform’s service registry (e.g., Kubernetes services, Consul services, etc.) and from the hosts declared by ServiceEntries and Unlike the virtual service’s host(s), the destination’s host must be a real destination that exists in Istio’s service registry or Envoy won’t know where to send traffic to it